# Specify App Pool and Authentication when creating a Virtual Directory via Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis-7

I have a powershell function I use to create virtual directories:

```
New-Item $commitpath -PhysicalPath $virtualdirPath -Type VirtualDirectory
```

But I need to be able to specify a DIFFERENT Authentication and a DIFFERENT App Pool than the parent website uses. Something like this:

```
New-Item $commitpath -PhysicalPath $virtualdirPath -Authentication "Anonymous" - AppPool "MyOtherAppPool" -Type VirtualDirectory
```

How do I do this via script?

Thanks,

Eric West

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [webadministration module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx) to configure the IIS.

Here is an example to create a new application pool named `MyNewPool` running as `Administrator` ([identitytype 3 = SpecificUser](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel)):

```powershell
Import-Module WebAdministration

$applicationPoolName = 'MyNewPool'
$UserName = 'Administrator'
$Password = '12345'

$applicatonPoolUri = "IIS:\AppPools\$applicationPoolName"
if (-not(Test-Path $applicatonPoolUri)) # check whether the application pool exists
{
    $applicationPool = ni $applicatonPoolUri
    $applicationPool.processModel.username = $UserName
    $applicationPool.processModel.password = $Password
    $applicationPool.processModel.identityType = 3
    $applicationPool | si           
}
```

After you created the application pool, you can create the website and assign the pool using the [New-Website cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790605.aspx):

```powershell
New-Website -name 'MyNewWebSite' `
        -port 80
        -ip '*' `
        -PhysicalPath $virtualdirPath `
        -ApplicationPool $applicationPoolName
```